# Team a player on button click (roblox studio)

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying this code

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    -- Change team color to "Really Blue"
    player.TeamColor = BrickColor.new("Really blue")

    -- Kill the player
    local character = player.Character
    if character then
        local humanoid = character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
        if humanoid then
            humanoid.Health = 0
        end
    end
end)
```

But for some reason when I press the button I do not get teamed.
I am new to coding the language is lua (roblox studio)

I've tried changing the color a couple times to different things all same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a player's team on the Client (in a LocalScript) so you'll want to use RemoteEvents to change the player's team.

First, add a RemoteEvent to ReplicatedStorage.

Then, the LocalScript should look something like this:

```
local rs = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    rs.Event:FireServer()
end)
```

Now, for the serverscript:

```
local rs = game:GetSerivce("ReplicatedStorage")
rs.Event.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)
  player.TeamColor = BrickColor.new("Really blue")
  local character = plr.Character
  if character then
    local humanoid = character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        humanoid.Health = 0
    end
  end
end
```